# MySQL how to find difference between max 2 values for the same customer_id

Tags: mysql

i have spent nearly 2 hours to do it, but i can not.

Let us think we have
[image: it].

I need to find the the max date for per user, and find the payment amount for it. Then subtract the 2nd biggest date's value for it.

Which is [image: it].

I have done the query which finds the biggest date and returns the row:

```
SELECT e.customer_id, e.payment_date,e.payment_amount
FROM customer e
    LEFT JOIN customer m
        ON e.customer_id = m.customer_id
        AND e.payment_date < m.payment_date
WHERE m.payment_date IS NULL
```

Which returns [image: this]. Now i need to subtract 51(2nd largest for the user1) from 78(largest for the user1)  for user1, 66(2nd largest for the user2)  from 88(largest for the user2) for user2, and 1(because there is no other payment_id for user3) from 103(largest for the user3) in user3. How can it be done?

Comment: please provide a [mre] for your query, because how shpuld the databse know that ot should remove these values

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand

Comment: How shpould the databse know that client nober one has to remove 51. As we don't know where the data is comming from we can't help. So read the link carefully and give example data, so that we can understand what you try to achieve

Comment: It has nothing to do with the inputs. I am working just in mysql and basic sql commands. I just try to understand the sql

Comment: "Now i need to subtract .... How can it be done?"   `SELECT 78-51, 88-66, 103-1;`

Comment: i have edited so that you can understand what i want @Luuk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images with text,. code or data, should not be used here. see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

The rest is simple sql and arithmetic

To get the second highest number you can use a subselect, which uses the   customer_id

> ```
> CREATE TABLE payments
>     (`payment_id` int, `customer_id` int, `payment_date` varchar(10), `payment_amount` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO payments
>     (`payment_id`, `customer_id`, `payment_date`, `payment_amount`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 1, '2019-07-03', 37),
>     (3, 1, '2019-07-21', 51),
>     (2, 1, '2019-06-03', 32),
>     (4, 1, '2019-07-25', 78),
>     (1, 2, '2019-05-30', 36),
>     (2, 2, '2019-06-05', 66),
>     (3, 2, '2019-08-01', 87),
>     (1, 3, '2019-08-01', 104)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `customer_id`
> , MAX(`payment_date`) AS `payment_date`
> , MAX(`payment_amount`) 
> - IFNULL((SELECT `payment_amount` FROM payments WHERE `customer_id` = p1.`customer_id` LIMIT 1,1),0) AS `payment_amount`
> FROM 
> payments p1
> GROUP BY `customer_id`
> ```
>
> ```
> customer_id | payment_date | payment_amount
> ----------: | :----------- | -------------:
>           1 | 2019-07-25   |             27
>           2 | 2019-08-01   |             21
>           3 | 2019-08-01   |            104
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd26c6a30107e6a1d06975f0a583a2a9)*